# How can I make something like a?b:c in python?

Tags: python, boolean

In java, I usually use

```
boolean x = a? b : c;
```

instead

```
if(a)
    boolean x = b;
else
    boolean x = c;
```

Is there any possibility for doing that in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
x = b if a else c
```

which means the same thing.